# Remove Darktable 3.0.1 installed by Software

Tags: apt, software-sources, darktable

I know this question had been asked before but no answer in former questions have worked. I, like many others, wish to have the latest version of Darktable and the software (at ubuntu) only offers 3.0.1. I have Ubuntu 20.04.
I have not installed it by using Snap and when I try to remove it by -sudo snap remove Darktable (just in case) I got this answer from the command prompt:

Snap darktable is not installed.

I tried to remove it in Software, but I got this error message:

```
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics:darktable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried something similar from the command prompt, but I got the same answer.

I don't want to have two Darktable versions installed on my computer, so how can I remove the old one installed from Software and get the latest version installed using snap?

Comment: I am sorry but no, I try to fix line 2 by adding ## and that did not help at all. I could not update it, it continue to complain about line 2. " E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics:darktable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
" And when I try to remove it from Software I get "Unable to remove darktable, removing not available" when I try to remove it. Best regards Mela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing.

> I have not installed it by using Snap

If you *did not* install Darktable via snap then snap remove won't do anything

Try:

`sudo apt purge darktable`

`sudo apt autoremove` (this shouldn't be necessary but I don't know what you have messed with)

`sudo snap install darktable`

I don't know if you are in a rush, but having two "versions" in this case won't be harm, the snap is self-contained (in case you need to work right now)

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much. The "Sudo apt purge darktable" did work ! :) Now I could get the latest version using snap. The  3.0.1 version was installed through Software. I am sorry that my question was difficult to understand, but you did solve it anyway. I am most grateful. Mela

Comment: @octoberleaves Glad it worked. You should mark my answer as correct so the mods can close the question.